# How to find the coefficient of $x^2y^3z^6$ in the expression $(x^2+y+z)^{10}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

How can find the coefficient of $x^2y^3z^6$  in the expression $(x^2+y+z)^{10}$?

I know this involves the binomial theorem, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: The coefficient is zero since one would have to choose x^2 once, y twice and z six times, all in six choices, which is impossible. Typo?

Comment: Typo, fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, and adapting the argument in my comment would give the answer right away. Can you?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/484908/321264

Answer (score 3):

We can apply the binomial theorem twice in order to find the coeffcient. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ of an expression.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^2y^3z^6](x^2+y+z)^{10}&=[x^2y^3z^6]\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}x^{2k}(y+z)^{10-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=[y^3z^6]\binom{10}{1}(y+z)^9\tag{2}\\
> &=10[y^3z^6]\sum_{k=0}^9\binom{9}{k}y^kz^{9-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=10\binom{9}{3}\tag{4}\\
> &=840
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theorem once to $(x^2+(y+z))^{10}$.
- In (2) we select the coefficient of $x^2$ which is given when the index $k=1$.
- In (3) apply the binomial theorem again.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $y^3z^6$ corresponding to the index $k=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The formula to find the coefficient of $x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r^2}\dots x_k^{r_k}$ in $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k)^n$ is:

$$\frac{n!}{r_1!r_2!\dots r_k!}$$

Here you take $x^2 =p$ say, then the problem reduced to finding coeff of  $py^3z^6$  in the expression $(p+y+z)^{10}$.

Ans: $$\frac{10!}{1!3! 6!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way may be intuitively helpful. How many different $10$-tuples can you make out of $x^{2}, y, y, y, z, z, z, z, z, z$? The number of each "character" corresponds to each of the exponent given; using the notion of tuple is due to the commutative multiplication law. Now treat the same letters as if they were different (something like $y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},...$, which you consider mentally.); then you have got $10!$ tuples certainly. But this is way too many! We have to tailor it by observing that this number is actually $3! \times 6!$ (due to the duplicates of $y$ and $z$, respectively.) times the required number! So the required number is
$$
\frac{10!}{3!6!}.
$$